# Laravel associate animal with multiple tags

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a tags table, and an animals table (for example) that are used for many purposes. I want to add a relationship that means each `animal` can have multiple `tags` associated with it:

```
class Animals extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'animals';
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Tags');
    }
}
```

However each `tag` can only contain 1 `animal_id`, whereas I need it to contain multiple `animal_ids`. How do I create an interim table which matches `animal_id` to `tag_id`? And then how do I use it?

```
animal_id    tag_id
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            1
3            1
```

So that when I do `App\Animals::first->tags()` it returns all the associated tags?

Answer (score 3):

For that you need three table.

One animals_table, tags_table and one table which hold relations between animanls and tags.

Suppose

table animals has id as primary_key

tags table primary key is id

and third table is animal_tags which has anumal_id and tag_id as foreign key.

Now in animal model relationship should be

```
public function tags(){
  return $this->hasmany(\App\animalTag::class,'animal_id','id')
}
```

In tags model relationship should be

```
public function animal(){
  return $this->hasMany(\App\animalTag::class,'tag_id','id');
}
```

Finally in animalTag model relationship should be

```
public function animal(){
  return $this->hasOne(\App\animal::class,'id','animal_id');
}

public function tag(){
 return $this->hasOne(\App\tag::class,'id','tag_id');
}
```

Now you can access

```
App\Animal::first->tags()
```

hope you understand my concept.

Answer (score 0):

Use `belongsToMany` which matches `many-to-many` relationship 
[link to documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)